# Fabric JS: Snapping guidelines not correctly positioned when zoomed

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

For my [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) project: I'm trying to setup object snapping and alignment guidelines. For snapping, this means when a user drags an object around, if any edge of the object comes close to alignment with another object edge, it will snap into place. During this time, guidelines appear as visual helpers for the user.

So far I'm implementing existing work, done by various fabric.js contributors, found here:

[centering_guidelines.js](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/blob/master/lib/centering_guidelines.js) & [aligning_guidelines.js](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/blob/master/lib/aligning_guidelines.js).

---

**WORKS:** At default zoom (1), object snapping and alignment guidelines work great!

**FAILS:** When zooming (in or out), the visual guidelines appear in the wrong position, however snapping maintains correct functionality.

---

**CODE SAMPLES:** Move objects around. At default zoom, snapping and guidelines work great. Change zoom level (with mousewheel) and notice guidelines are not positioned correctly, however snapping works fine.

**Sample 1: Simple**

Original libraries loaded as-is; simple demo.

https://codepen.io/MarsAndBack/pen/ZEQMXoM

**Sample 2: Detailed**

Original libraries copy-pasted inline, with modifications to help investigation.

https://codepen.io/MarsAndBack/pen/LYGJGoq

Note: Codepen has full code.

```js
// ==========================================
// SETUP
// ==========================================

const canvas = new fabric.Canvas("myCanvas")
canvas.backgroundColor = "#222222";
var lastClientX = 0
var lastClientY = 0
var state = "default"
const outer = null
const box1 = null
const box2 = null
this.centerLine_horizontal = ""
this.centerLine_vertical = ""
this.alignmentLines_horizontal = ""
this.alignmentLines_vertical = ""

fabric.Object.prototype.set({
  cornerSize: 15,
  cornerStyle: 'circle',
  cornerColor: '#ffffff',
  transparentCorners: false
})

setupObjects()
updateInfo(canvas)

function setupObjects() {

  this.outer = new fabric.Rect({
    width: canvas.getWidth(),
    height: canvas.getHeight(),
    top: 20,
    left: 20,
    stroke: '#ffffff',
    evented: false,
    selectable: false
  })

  this.box1 = new fabric.Rect({
    width: 240,
    height: 100,
    top: 20,
    left: 20,
    fill: '#fff28a',
    myType: "box"
  })

  this.box2 = new fabric.Rect({
    width: 240,
    height: 100,
    top: 140,
    left: 20,
    fill: '#ff8a8a',
    myType: "box"
  })

  this.box3 = new fabric.Rect({
    width: 100,
    height: 160,
    top: 20,
    left: 280,
    fill: '#cf8aff',
    myType: "box"
  })

  canvas.add(this.outer)
  this.outer.center()

  canvas.add(this.box1)
  canvas.add(this.box2)
  canvas.add(this.box3)
  let allBoxes = new fabric.ActiveSelection(canvas.getObjects().filter(obj => obj.myType == "box"), {
    canvas: canvas
  })
  allBoxes.center()
  allBoxes.destroy()
}



function updateInfo() {
  let info_zoom = document.getElementById('info_zoom')
  let info_vptTop = document.getElementById('info_vptTop')
  let info_vptLeft = document.getElementById('info_vptLeft')
  let info_centerLine_horizontal = document.getElementById('info_centerLine_horizontal')
  let info_centerLine_vertical = document.getElementById('info_centerLine_vertical')
  let info_alignmentLines_horizontal = document.getElementById('info_alignmentLines_horizontal')
  let info_alignmentLines_vertical = document.getElementById('info_alignmentLines_vertical')

  info_zoom.innerHTML = canvas.getZoom().toFixed(2)
  info_vptTop.innerHTML = Math.round(canvas.viewportTransform[5])
  info_vptLeft.innerHTML = Math.round(canvas.viewportTransform[4])
  info_centerLine_horizontal.innerHTML = this.centerLine_horizontal
  info_centerLine_vertical.innerHTML = this.centerLine_vertical
  info_alignmentLines_horizontal.innerHTML = this.alignmentLines_horizontal
  info_alignmentLines_vertical.innerHTML = this.alignmentLines_vertical

}

// ------------------------------------
// Reset
// ------------------------------------
let resetButton = document.getElementById('reset')

resetButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  reset()
}, false)

function reset() {
  canvas.remove(...canvas.getObjects())
  setupObjects()
  canvas.setViewportTransform([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])
  updateInfo()
}
// ------------------------------------





// ==========================================
// MOUSE INTERACTIONS
// ==========================================

// MOUSEWHEEL ZOOM
canvas.on('mouse:wheel', (opt) => {
  let delta = 0

  // -------------------------------
  // WHEEL RESOLUTION
  let wheelDelta = opt.e.wheelDelta
  let deltaY = opt.e.deltaY

  // CHROME WIN/MAC | SAFARI 7 MAC | OPERA WIN/MAC | EDGE
  if (wheelDelta) {
    delta = -wheelDelta / 120
  }
  // FIREFOX WIN / MAC | IE
  if (deltaY) {
    deltaY > 0 ? delta = 1 : delta = -1
  }
  // -------------------------------

  let pointer = canvas.getPointer(opt.e)
  let zoom = canvas.getZoom()
  zoom = zoom - delta / 10

  // limit zoom in
  if (zoom > 4) zoom = 4

  // limit zoom out
  if (zoom < 0.2) {
    zoom = 0.2
  }

  //canvas.zoomToPoint({
  //  x: opt.e.offsetX,
  //  y: opt.e.offsetY
  //}, zoom)

  canvas.zoomToPoint(
    new fabric.Point(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2),
    zoom);

  opt.e.preventDefault()
  opt.e.stopPropagation()

  canvas.renderAll()
  canvas.calcOffset()

  updateInfo(canvas)
})




initCenteringGuidelines(canvas)
initAligningGuidelines(canvas)



// ==========================================
// CANVAS CENTER SNAPPING & ALIGNMENT GUIDELINES
// ==========================================

// ORIGINAL:
// https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/blob/master/lib/centering_guidelines.js

/**
 * Augments canvas by assigning to `onObjectMove` and `onAfterRender`.
 * This kind of sucks because other code using those methods will stop functioning.
 * Need to fix it by replacing callbacks with pub/sub kind of subscription model.
 * (or maybe use existing fabric.util.fire/observe (if it won't be too slow))
 */
function initCenteringGuidelines(canvas) {

  let canvasWidth = canvas.getWidth(),
    canvasHeight = canvas.getHeight(),
    canvasWidthCenter = canvasWidth / 2,
    canvasHeightCenter = canvasHeight / 2,
    canvasWidthCenterMap = {},
    canvasHeightCenterMap = {},
    centerLineMargin = 4,
    centerLineColor = 'purple',
    centerLineWidth = 2,
    ctx = canvas.getSelectionContext(),
    viewportTransform

  for (let i = canvasWidthCenter - centerLineMargin, len = canvasWidthCenter + centerLineMargin; i <= len; i++) {
    canvasWidthCenterMap[Math.round(i)] = true
  }
  for (let i = canvasHeightCenter - centerLineMargin, len = canvasHeightCenter + centerLineMargin; i <= len; i++) {
    canvasHeightCenterMap[Math.round(i)] = true
  }

  function showVerticalCenterLine() {
    showCenterLine(canvasWidthCenter + 0.5, 0, canvasWidthCenter + 0.5, canvasHeight)
  }

  function showHorizontalCenterLine() {
    showCenterLine(0, canvasHeightCenter + 0.5, canvasWidth, canvasHeightCenter + 0.5)
  }

  function showCenterLine(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    ctx.save()
    ctx.strokeStyle = centerLineColor
    ctx.lineWidth = centerLineWidth
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.moveTo(x1 * viewportTransform[0], y1 * viewportTransform[3])
    ctx.lineTo(x2 * viewportTransform[0], y2 * viewportTransform[3])
    ctx.stroke()
    ctx.restore()
  }

  let afterRenderActions = [],
    isInVerticalCenter,
    isInHorizontalCenter

  canvas.on('mouse:down', () => {
    isInVerticalCenter = isInHorizontalCenter = null
    this.centerLine_horizontal = ""
    this.centerLine_vertical = ""
    updateInfo()
    viewportTransform = canvas.viewportTransform
  })

  canvas.on('object:moving', function(e) {
    let object = e.target,
      objectCenter = object.getCenterPoint(),
      transform = canvas._currentTransform

    if (!transform) return

    isInVerticalCenter = Math.round(objectCenter.x) in canvasWidthCenterMap,
      isInHorizontalCenter = Math.round(objectCenter.y) in canvasHeightCenterMap

    if (isInHorizontalCenter || isInVerticalCenter) {
      object.setPositionByOrigin(new fabric.Point((isInVerticalCenter ? canvasWidthCenter : objectCenter.x), (isInHorizontalCenter ? canvasHeightCenter : objectCenter.y)), 'center', 'center')
    }
  })

  canvas.on('before:render', function() {
    canvas.clearContext(canvas.contextTop)
  })

  canvas.on('after:render', () => {
    if (isInVerticalCenter) {
      showVerticalCenterLine()
      this.centerLine_horizontal = ""
      this.centerLine_vertical = (canvasWidthCenter + 0.5) + ", " + 0 + ", " + (canvasWidthCenter + 0.5) + ", " + canvasHeight
    }

    if (isInHorizontalCenter) {
      showHorizontalCenterLine()
      this.centerLine_horizontal = (canvasWidthCenter + 0.5) + ", " + 0 + ", " + (canvasWidthCenter + 0.5) + ", " + canvasHeight
      this.centerLine_vertical = ""
    }


    updateInfo()


  })

  canvas.on('mouse:up', function() {
    // clear these values, to stop drawing guidelines once mouse is up
    canvas.renderAll()
  })

}




// ===============================================
// OBJECT SNAPPING & ALIGNMENT GUIDELINES
// ===============================================

// ORIGINAL:
// https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/blob/master/lib/aligning_guidelines.js


// Original author:
/**
 * Should objects be aligned by a bounding box?
 * [Bug] Scaled objects sometimes can not be aligned by edges
 *
 */
function initAligningGuidelines(canvas) {

  let ctx = canvas.getSelectionContext(),
    aligningLineOffset = 5,
    aligningLineMargin = 4,
    aligningLineWidth = 2,
    aligningLineColor = 'lime',
    viewportTransform,
    zoom = null,
    verticalLines = [],
    horizontalLines = [],
    canvasContainer = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
    containerWidth = canvasContainer.offsetWidth,
    containerHeight = canvasContainer.offsetHeight

  function drawVerticalLine(coords) {
    drawLine(
      coords.x + 0.5, coords.y1 > coords.y2 ? coords.y2 : coords.y1,
      coords.x + 0.5, coords.y2 > coords.y1 ? coords.y2 : coords.y1
    )
  }

  function drawHorizontalLine(coords) {
    drawLine(
      coords.x1 > coords.x2 ? coords.x2 : coords.x1, coords.y + 0.5,
      coords.x2 > coords.x1 ? coords.x2 : coords.x1, coords.y + 0.5
    )
  }

  function drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    ctx.save()
    ctx.lineWidth = aligningLineWidth
    ctx.strokeStyle = aligningLineColor
    ctx.beginPath()
    //console.log("x1 :" + x1)
    //console.log("viewportTransform[4] :" + viewportTransform[4])
    //console.log("zoom :" + zoom)
    ctx.moveTo(
      ((x1 + viewportTransform[4]) * zoom),
      ((y1 + viewportTransform[5]) * zoom)
    )
    //console.log("-------")
    //console.log("x1 :" + x1)
    //console.log("viewportTransform[4] :" + viewportTransform[4])
    //console.log("zoom :" + zoom)
    //console.log("x :" + (x1 + canvas.viewportTransform[4]) * zoom)

    ctx.lineTo(
      ((x2 + viewportTransform[4]) * zoom),
      ((y2 + viewportTransform[5]) * zoom)
    )
    ctx.stroke()
    ctx.restore()
  }

  function isInRange(value1, value2) {
    value1 = Math.round(value1)
    value2 = Math.round(value2)
    for (var i = value1 - aligningLineMargin, len = value1 + aligningLineMargin; i <= len; i++) {
      if (i === value2) {
        return true
      }
    }
    return false;
  }




  canvas.on('mouse:down', function() {
    verticalLines.length = horizontalLines.length = 0
    viewportTransform = canvas.viewportTransform
    zoom = canvas.getZoom()
  })

  canvas.on('object:moving', (e) => {

    verticalLines.length = horizontalLines.length = 0

    let activeObject = e.target,
      canvasObjects = canvas.getObjects().filter(obj => obj.myType == "box"),
      activeObjectCenter = activeObject.getCenterPoint(),
      activeObjectLeft = activeObjectCenter.x,
      activeObjectTop = activeObjectCenter.y,
      activeObjectBoundingRect = activeObject.getBoundingRect(),
      activeObjectHeight = activeObjectBoundingRect.height / viewportTransform[3],
      activeObjectWidth = activeObjectBoundingRect.width / viewportTransform[0],
      horizontalInTheRange = false,
      verticalInTheRange = false,
      transform = canvas._currentTransform;

    //console.log("|||||||||")
    //console.log("active acoords is: " + JSON.stringify(activeObject.aCoords, null, 4))
    //console.log("active acoords is: " + JSON.stringify(activeObject.oCoords, null, 4))
    //console.log("active left offset is: " + JSON.stringify(activeObject.aCoords, null, 4))
    //containerWidth = canvasContainer.offsetWidth
    //containerHeight = canvasContainer.offsetHeight
    //console.log("active left from container is: " + (containerWidth - this.outer.width) / 2 + activeObject.aCoords.tl.x )

    if (!transform) return;

    // It should be trivial to DRY this up by encapsulating (repeating) creation of x1, x2, y1, and y2 into functions,
    // but we're not doing it here for perf. reasons -- as this a function that's invoked on every mouse move

    for (let i = canvasObjects.length; i--;) {

      if (canvasObjects[i] === activeObject) continue

      let objectCenter = canvasObjects[i].getCenterPoint(),
        objectLeft = objectCenter.x,
        objectTop = objectCenter.y,
        objectBoundingRect = canvasObjects[i].getBoundingRect(),
        objectHeight = objectBoundingRect.height / viewportTransform[3],
        objectWidth = objectBoundingRect.width / viewportTransform[0]

      // snap by the horizontal center line
      if (isInRange(objectLeft, activeObjectLeft)) {
        verticalInTheRange = true
        verticalLines.push({
          x: objectLeft,
          y1: (objectTop < activeObjectTop) ?
            (objectTop - objectHeight / 2 - aligningLineOffset) :
            (objectTop + objectHeight / 2 + aligningLineOffset),
          y2: (activeObjectTop > objectTop) ?
            (activeObjectTop + activeObjectHeight / 2 + aligningLineOffset) :
            (activeObjectTop - activeObjectHeight / 2 - aligningLineOffset)
        })
        activeObject.setPositionByOrigin(new fabric.Point(objectLeft, activeObjectTop), 'center', 'center');
      }

      // snap by the left edge
      if (isInRange(objectLeft - objectWidth / 2, activeObjectLeft - activeObjectWidth / 2)) {
        verticalInTheRange = true
        verticalLines.push({
          x: objectLeft - objectWidth / 2,
          y1: (objectTop < activeObjectTop) ?
            (objectTop - objectHeight / 2 - aligningLineOffset) :
            (objectTop + objectHeight / 2 + aligningLineOffset),
          y2: (activeObjectTop > objectTop) ?
            (activeObjectTop + activeObjectHeight / 2 + aligningLineOffset) :
            (activeObjectTop - activeObjectHeight / 2 - aligningLineOffset)
        })
        activeObject.setPositionByOrigin(new fabric.Point(objectLeft - objectWidth / 2 + activeObjectWidth / 2, activeObjectTop), 'center', 'center')
      }

      // snap by the right edge
      if (isInRange(objectLeft + objectWidth / 2, activeObjectLeft + activeObjectWidth / 2)) {
        verticalInTheRange = true
        verticalLines.push({
          x: objectLeft + objectWidth / 2,
          y1: (objectTop < activeObjectTop) ?
            (objectTop - objectHeight / 2 - aligningLineOffset) :
            (objectTop + objectHeight / 2 + aligningLineOffset),
          y2: (activeObjectTop > objectTop) ?
            (activeObjectTop + activeObjectHeight / 2 + aligningLineOffset) :
            (activeObjectTop - activeObjectHeight / 2 - aligningLineOffset)
        })
        activeObject.setPositionByOrigin(new fabric.Point(objectLeft + objectWidth / 2 - activeObjectWidth / 2, activeObjectTop), 'center', 'center')
      }

      // snap by the vertical center line
      if (isInRange(objectTop, activeObjectTop)) {
        horizontalInTheRange = true;
        horizontalLines.push({
          y: objectTop,
          x1: (objectLeft < activeObjectLeft) ?
            (objectLeft - objectWidth / 2 - aligningLineOffset) :
            (objectLeft + objectWidth / 2 + aligningLineOffset),
          x2: (activeObjectLeft > objectLeft) ?
            (activeObjectLeft + activeObjectWidth / 2 + aligningLineOffset) :
            (activeObjectLeft - activeObjectWidth / 2 - aligningLineOffset)
        })
        activeObject.setPositionByOrigin(new fabric.Point(activeObjectLeft, objectTop), 'center', 'center')
      }

      // snap by the top edge
      if (isInRange(objectTop - objectHeight / 2, activeObjectTop - activeObjectHeight / 2)) {
        horizontalInTheRange = true
        horizontalLines.push({
          y: objectTop - objectHeight / 2,
          x1: (objectLeft < activeObjectLeft) ?
            (objectLeft - objectWidth / 2 - aligningLineOffset) :
            (objectLeft + objectWidth / 2 + aligningLineOffset),
          x2: (activeObjectLeft > objectLeft) ?
            (activeObjectLeft + activeObjectWidth / 2 + aligningLineOffset) :
            (activeObjectLeft - activeObjectWidth / 2 - aligningLineOffset)
        })
        activeObject.setPositionByOrigin(new fabric.Point(activeObjectLeft, objectTop - objectHeight / 2 + activeObjectHeight / 2), 'center', 'center');
      }

      // snap by the bottom edge
      if (isInRange(objectTop + objectHeight / 2, activeObjectTop + activeObjectHeight / 2)) {
        horizontalInTheRange = true
        horizontalLines.push({
          y: objectTop + objectHeight / 2,
          x1: (objectLeft < activeObjectLeft) ?
            (objectLeft - objectWidth / 2 - aligningLineOffset) :
            (objectLeft + objectWidth / 2 + aligningLineOffset),
          x2: (activeObjectLeft > objectLeft) ?
            (activeObjectLeft + activeObjectWidth / 2 + aligningLineOffset) :
            (activeObjectLeft - activeObjectWidth / 2 - aligningLineOffset)
        })
        activeObject.setPositionByOrigin(new fabric.Point(activeObjectLeft, objectTop + objectHeight / 2 - activeObjectHeight / 2), 'center', 'center')
      }
    }

    if (!horizontalInTheRange) {
      horizontalLines.length = 0
    }

    if (!verticalInTheRange) {
      verticalLines.length = 0
    }
  })

  canvas.on('mouse:wheel', (opt) => {
    verticalLines.length = horizontalLines.length = 0
  })

  canvas.on('before:render', function() {
    canvas.clearContext(canvas.contextTop)
  })

  canvas.on('after:render', () => {
    for (let i = verticalLines.length; i--;) {
      drawVerticalLine(verticalLines[i])
    }
    for (let i = horizontalLines.length; i--;) {
      drawHorizontalLine(horizontalLines[i])
    }


    this.alignmentLines_horizontal = JSON.stringify(horizontalLines, null, 4)
    this.alignmentLines_vertical = JSON.stringify(verticalLines, null, 4)
    updateInfo()

    // console.log("activeObject left edge x is: " + canvas.getActiveObject().left)

    //verticalLines.length = horizontalLines.length = 0

    canvas.calcOffset()
  })

  canvas.on('mouse:up', () => {
    //verticalLines.length = horizontalLines.length = 0
    canvas.renderAll()
    //this.alignmentLines_horizontal = horizontalLines
    //this.alignmentLines_vertical = verticalLines
    //updateInfo()
  })



}
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#header {
  display: flex;
}

#reset {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 1em;
  border: none;
  margin: 0.5em;
  margin-top: 6em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#reset:hover {
  background-color: #666666;
}

#reset:active {
  background-color: #333333;
}

#info {
  /* display: flex; */
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#info>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#info>div>div {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}

hr {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://pagecdn.io/lib/fabric/3.6.3/fabric.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>

  <div id="sidebar">
    <button id="reset">RESET</button>

    <div id="info">

      <div>
        <div><b>zoom:</b>
          <div id="info_zoom"></div>
        </div>
        <div><b>viewport top:</b>
          <div id="info_vptTop"></div>
        </div>
        <div><b>viewport left:</b>
          <div id="info_vptLeft"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr />

      <div>
        <div><b>Alignment lines (green)</b></div>
        <div><b>Horizontal:</b>
          <div id="info_alignmentLines_horizontal"></div>
        </div>
        <div><b>Vertical:</b>
          <div id="info_alignmentLines_vertical"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr />

      <div>
        <div><b>Canvas-center lines (purple)</b></div>
        <div><b>Horizontal:</b>
          <div id="info_centerLine_horizontal"></div>
        </div>
        <div><b>Vertical:</b>
          <div id="info_centerLine_vertical"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I changed `drawLine` function.Should work
https://jsfiddle.net/3mtcsy6p/1/

```
 function drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    var originXY = fabric.util.transformPoint(new fabric.Point(x1, y1), canvas.viewportTransform),
                dimensions = fabric.util.transformPoint(new fabric.Point(x2, y2),canvas.viewportTransform);
    ctx.save()
    ctx.lineWidth = aligningLineWidth
    ctx.strokeStyle = aligningLineColor
    ctx.beginPath()
   
    ctx.moveTo(
      ( (originXY.x ) ),
      ( (originXY.y ) )
    )
   
    
    ctx.lineTo(
      ( (dimensions.x ) ),
      ( (dimensions.y ) )
    )
    ctx.stroke()
    ctx.restore()
  }
```

Comment: Hey thanks, this works great! The same logic applied to the purple canvas-center lines also worked.

Answer (score 2):

A more performant way would be to do the calculation directly in drawLine function insted of calling another one. As the function is called on every mouse movement, performance is important.

The new function:

```
    function drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
      ctx.save();
      ctx.lineWidth = aligningLineWidth;
      ctx.strokeStyle = aligningLineColor;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(((x1*zoom+viewportTransform[4])), ((y1*zoom+viewportTransform[5])));
      ctx.lineTo(((x2*zoom+viewportTransform[4])), ((y2*zoom+viewportTransform[5])));
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.restore();
    }
```

The code pen: https://codepen.io/Theluiz-eduardo/pen/abqMVGV

Just out of curiosity, a performance test calling the function vs calculating directly:

```js
  const ctx = {}, canvas = {}, fabric = { util: {} }
  
  ctx.moveTo = () => true;
  ctx.lineTo = () => true;
  
  canvas.viewportTransform = [0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 200, 100]
  canvas.getZoom = () => 0.5;
  
  fabric.util.transformPoint = function(p, t, ignoreOffset) {
      if (ignoreOffset) {
        return fabric.Point(
          t[0] * p.x + t[2] * p.y,
          t[1] * p.x + t[3] * p.y
        );
      }
      return fabric.Point(
        t[0] * p.x + t[2] * p.y + t[4],
        t[1] * p.x + t[3] * p.y + t[5]
      );
    }
  
  fabric.Point = (x, y) => ({x: x, y: y})
  
  const x1 = 10, x2 = 15, y1 = 20, y2 = 25, zoom = canvas.getZoom()

  function performTest(fun, name, repeat) {
    console.time(name)

    while (repeat--) {
      fun()
    }
    console.timeEnd(name)
  }
  
  const callingFun = () => {
        var originXY = fabric.util.transformPoint(fabric.Point(x1, y1), canvas.viewportTransform),
        dimensions = fabric.util.transformPoint(fabric.Point(x2, y2),canvas.viewportTransform);
    ctx.moveTo(originXY.x, originXY.y)
    ctx.lineTo(dimensions.x, dimensions.y)
  }
  
  const directCalc = () => {
    ctx.moveTo(((x1*zoom+canvas.viewportTransform[4])), ((y1*zoom+canvas.viewportTransform[5])));
    ctx.lineTo(((x2*zoom+canvas.viewportTransform[4])), ((y2*zoom+canvas.viewportTransform[5])));
  }
  
  performTest(directCalc, 'directCalc', 10**8)
  performTest(callingFun, 'callingFun', 10**8)
```

Comment: Great, how to add a snap functionality to left of the object is snapping to other objects' right?